# Splitting lines that are not contiguous (Creating a leak detection dataset)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, splitting

I am having trouble with one of the steps of a very long model. The goal is to generate a dataset of the water lines that have been "inspected" by our leak detection devices.  The devices supposedly will "inspect" all pipe that is 500 feet from the detector, as long as it is connected within that 500 foot buffer.  See attached image.  The green star represents a leak detection device.  The resulting inspected pipe will be all pipe within the circle (500 foot buffer) except the ones highlighted in yellow because they connect outside of that 500 foot buffer.  I have tried many ways to achieve this in a model (I need to run this weekly for 3000 miles of pipe), but cannot find an automated way of doing this.  My plan was to merge the pipe that is inside the buffer, then remove the sections that are not contiguous with the portion that intersects with the leak detection point, but I have not found a way to do that.
Anyone have any thoughts on this?
[image]

Comment: What software, modeling environment, and/or programming language should possible solutions include?

Comment: What particular software, modeling environment, and/or programming language are you wanting to ask about in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ArcGIS terminology but any GIS should have these tools.
Create the leak device buffer polygon, 500 ft
 Clip Water lines by the    device Buffer
 Dissolve Water lines, multipart
 Buffer Water lines, 1    foot 
Convert Water line Buffers Multipart-to-Singlepart
  Select-by-Location Singlepart Buffers that Intersect device point
 Reverse  Selection Set of Singlepart Buffers
 Select-by-Location original Water    lines that Intersect Singlepart Buffers
 The unconnected lines should    now be selected

Comment: Yes, this did it.  I was missing the Convert Water line Buffers Multipart-to-Singlepart section. THANKS!!

Comment: One more question, if you don't mind.  I have written most of the models and all is working great until the step where I select the singlepart buffers that intersect with device point. The issue is that there are many device points.  How would you go about selecting the buffers that intersect with only the device point that is the centroid of the buffer?

Comment: If you create a Layer of just Devices, you might use "Iterate Feature Selection" to loop through a device at a time. Most tools will honor a Selected Set, these must be a Feature Layer of course.

Comment: I tried that, but the problem is that I need to iterate through both the devices and the singlepart buffers.  I tried creating three separate models to achieve that - iterate through devices, iterate through singlepart buffers, drag both of those outputs into new model and use those outputs for the selection, but the Select Layer By Location tool will not accept the output of a feature class iterator as the Input Feature Layer.